# Identifying missing component from vintage synthesizer

Tags: pcb, identification, vintage, synthesizer

I acquired a [Hillwood C-1A](https://www.matrixsynth.com/2019/06/hillwood-c-1a-70s-rare-vintage-electric.html) synthesizer with a burnt circuit board with 3 empty holes where a part needs to go. I'd like to repair the board but I don't know what component to look for... Help?

The product info specifies the following, if it helps:
`1 LSI, 8 IC, 132 Transistor, 248 Diode`

[image: PCB with missing 3-pin component]

Comment: does the heatsink have a hole it top left in the picture? ... it may have been rotated 180 degrees from the original orientation

Comment: It may be more clear if you can reverse-engineer the whole circuit board, producing a circuit diagram.

Answer (score 2):

Without a schematic, picture of the original or in depth knowlege of the unit, then determining what the missing component is tends to be rather tricky. I'd sketch out the circuitry of that board and from that inferring what the missing component is should be a lot easier.

A clear picture of the solder side of the board and the top side might aid us in assisting as the board doesn't look too complicated. Labelling the wires as well will help.

If you're lucky, a reader here might have specific knowlege of your unit and be able to comment.

Asking the question on eevblog or specialist synth sites might be another avenue.

Comment: information seems a bit thin on the ground for this unit. Some detailed pictures would help yourself and maybe others that have this unit.

Answer (score 1):

That board looks like a power supply. The missing component is positioned next to what looks like a heat sink. I’m guessing the missing component is either a large pass transistor or a voltage regulator IC in TO-220 package.